# Убрать вывод страны

Tags: javascript

Стоит скрипт http://webersoft.ru/select-ajax-mysql/
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в нем убрать вообще выбор страны, чтобы было только регион и город. Спасибо

Comment: В селекте регионов вывести регионы, убрать поле страны и лишний аjax запрос для получения регионов. удалить get_regions.php за ненадобностью. Для себя Вам нужно понять логику работы скрипта прежде чем его использовать.

Comment: Пример кода должен содержаться в самом вопросе. Ссылки позволительны только для уточнения

Comment: В форме добавить options регионов в select регионов. Там идет подзагрузка с php файла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Убрать лишний `select` для выбора стран из формы
2. В форме добавить `options` регионов в `select` регионов
3. В строке `<select name="region_id" id="region_id" disabled="disabled" class="StyleSelectBox">` удаляете `disabled="disabled"`.
4. В файле `selects.js` удаляете лишний ajax запрос для получения стран
5. Удаляете файл получения регионов *get_regions.php*
   за ненадобностью.

```js
/*selects.js*/
/* 
 * При полной загрузке документа
 * мы начинаем определять события
 */
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*
   * Те же действия проделываем с выбором города&nbsp;
   */
  $('#region_id').change(function() {
    var region_id = $('#region_id :selected').val();
    if (region_id == '0') {
      $('#city_id').html('<option>- выберите город -</option>');
      $('#city_id').attr('disabled', true);
      return (false);
    }
    $('#city_id').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#city_id').html('<option>загрузка...</option>');
    var url = 'get_city.php';
    $.get(
      url,
      "region_id=" + region_id,

      function(result) {
        if (result.type == 'error') {
          alert('error');
          return (false);
        } else {
          var options = '';
          $(result.citys).each(function() {
            options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('city_id') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>';
          });

          $('#city_id').html('<option>- выберите город -</option>' + options);
          $('#city_id').attr('disabled', false);
        }
      },
      "json"
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="get">
  Регион:
  <br />
  <select name="region_id" id="region_id" class="StyleSelectBox">
    <option value="0">- выберите регион -</option>
    <!-- Здесь добавляете options со всеми регионами -->
  </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    Город:
    <br />
    <select name="city_id" id="city_id" disabled="disabled" class="StyleSelectBox">
      <option value="0">- выберите город -</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Alex можно корректный код пожалуйста?

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, какой код Вам нужен. В ответе указан конечный код формы и конечный код `selects.js`. Вам нужно лишь добавить в форму `options` регионов. и использовать файл получения городов из указанного Вами скрипта.

Comment: В Html я сделал, если можно select.js. Сделал чтобы select  регионом был кликабельным не работает            <label for="region_id">Выберите регион:</label><br/>
            <select name="region_id" id="region_id" disabled="disabled" class="StyleSelectBox">
                <option value="0">- выберите регион -</option>
            </select><br/>
            <label for="name">Выберите город:</label><br/>
            <select name="name" id="name" disabled="disabled" class="StyleSelectBox">
                <option value="0">- выберите город -</option>
            </select><br/>

Comment: а кроме формы, что Вы сделали? подключили скрипты, настроили подключение к бд или нет?

Comment: Да я все подключил все работает, но мне нужно только регион и город, т.е без выбора страны

Comment: в указанном в комментариях коде Вы не убрали `disabled="disabled"` для регионов. демо для Вашего кода https://jsfiddle.net/vLw2bgh6/

Comment: Понятно, но можно сделать так, чтобы как раньше список регионов грузился с бд?

Comment: конечно, поставьте ajax на получение регионов при загрузке страницы.  пример https://jsfiddle.net/vLw2bgh6/3/ в строке 8 javascript поставьте нужно Вам значение страны.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, поставил вместо 8, 3159 так в таблице mysql отображается Россия, при нажатии на кнопку регионы, ничего не отображается. Вроде начали выпадать регионы, но города не выпадают

Comment: а что возвращает Вам запрос ajax?

Comment: Как посмотреть?

Comment: посмотреть Вы можете через консоль.
приведенное намми решение работает, демо https://goo.gl/q5TQVo
кроме этого следует учитывать что скрипт использует устаревшее расширение mysql, которое давно не поддерживается php v.5.4 и старше. Если дадите ссылку на Вашу тестовую страницу сможем посмотреть в чем у Вас проблема.